Какие фазы у сборщика мусора на C#?
Решил почитать про сборщик мусора в C# и столкнулся с разными ответами на вопрос: какие фазу у сборщика мусора?
Рихтер пишет что сначала идет фаза маркировки, потом идет фаза сжатия, на которой маркированные объекты смещаются вниз в смежный блок памяти, потом меняются ссылки, и потом как я понимаю удаляются мусорные объекты. То есть дефрагментация происходит до удаления мусорных объектов.
Где-то читал что сначала удаляются объекты, потом происходит дефрагментация.
Так же видел инфу, что идет фаза маркировки, потом какая-то фаза планирования, потом удаление.
Может кто-нибудь дать точный ответ, в каком порядке и какие фазы выполняются? Когда происходит дефрагментация? Если судить по Рихтеру, то она происходит всегда (в SOH естественно).

Смотрите документацию. Если владеете английским, то лучше в оригинале. / За время существования дотнета сборка мусора неоднократно менялась. Поэтому книги и статьи прошлых лет (тот же Рихтер) могут содержать устаревшую информацию. / LOH - это куча больших объектов. В ней компактирование по дефолту не происходит. Уверены, что не путаете с SOH? А ещё есть POH...

@AlexanderPetrov да, вы правы. Я перепутал SOH и LOH.

Ну чисто по логике странно сначала дефрагментировать, а потом удалять мусор, оставляя новые пропуски в местах где удалились объекты.

@CrazyElf Рихтер пишет что все маркированные объекты смещаются вниз, то есть получается что сверху остается лишь мусор, и при его очистке получается вся часть чистая как я понял. Я это представить не могу, но по логике понял так.
